# Click a thumbnail and show 3d model in browser

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, three.js, filesystems, 3d-model

I want to implement a function like [yobi3d](https://www.yobi3d.com/q/bike): click a bike thumbnail, then new window popup and show model to user. I put my models in file system, and I double checked that my model url is right through browser(I can download it by visit url(localhost/models/blabla.stl) in browser). But my popup window has no model to show(I am using threejs), I guess that it's because that the url pass to threejs would not download model so I guess that I have to implement a controller to handle /model request in my spring project. But where to store the downloaded model? Does anyone have idea how to implement that function?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: **1)** Open the developer console to ensure you aren't getting any 404 errors. **2)** If you're still getting 404s, try using a FQDN (fully-qualified domain name) in your URL, rather than a relative path. From your example, it should be `http://localhost/models/blabla.stl`. **3)** Ensure your server is configured to serve STL files with the correct MIME Type. You'll need to check your server documentation on how to do that. **4)** If none of that worked, please update your question that you've taken these troubleshooting steps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I figure out that's due to CORS problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's due to CORS problem. this [solution](https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html) works for me,